# How to get the original file from a renamed file from the github API?

Tags: git, github-api

Looking at https://api.github.com/repos/shamoons/testrepo/commits/10c71ca13d09fa4a2009888cca9d8433c6eac188 as an example, we see that there now exists a file called `renamedfile.js`. My question is.. how can I determine what this file was before?

If I look at the [parent commit](https://api.github.com/repos/shamoons/testrepo/commits/e55c7647c988cbf836294d25139f9c95e16b25c0), I can see that it was `newfile.js` before. But what if that commit had many files edited / added? How would I be able to tell?

Comment: You could also write to [GitHub's support](https://github.com/contact). A "old_filename" property is lacking and would be nice in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this, but you could accomplish it reliably with the following:

1. Get the tree of the "rename" commit (["rename" commit's tree URL](https://api.github.com/repos/shamoons/testrepo/git/trees/eb79f09cdc2a547046be815bd2af9d3e6098c0ac))
2. Get the hash of the "renamed" file (11096a58b82b44aab2fda131badf668ea9272783)
3. Get the parents of the "rename" commit (["rename" commit's parent URL](https://api.github.com/repos/shamoons/testrepo/commits/e55c7647c988cbf836294d25139f9c95e16b25c0))
4. Find a file with the same hash as your "renamed" file within one of the "rename" commits' parent commits, or trees of the same. This is the original file.

Comment: Is the hash a SHA1 of the file itself or is it some other hashing?

Comment: This works, however the files list is limited to 300 without pagination, so anything past "file 301" simply won't appear anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a field for that specified in the GitHub API.
If you look at the supplied API call there is a field name `previous_filename`

```
"files": [
  {
    "sha": "11096a58b82b44aab2fda131badf668ea9272783",
    "filename": "renamedfile.js",
    "status": "renamed",
    "additions": 0,
    "deletions": 0,
    "changes": 0,
    "blob_url": "https://github.com/shamoons/testrepo/blob/10c71ca13d09fa4a2009888cca9d8433c6eac188/renamedfile.js",
    "raw_url": "https://github.com/shamoons/testrepo/raw/10c71ca13d09fa4a2009888cca9d8433c6eac188/renamedfile.js",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/shamoons/testrepo/contents/renamedfile.js?ref=10c71ca13d09fa4a2009888cca9d8433c6eac188",
    "previous_filename": "newfile.js"
  }
]
```

(I know this is an old question but I thought why not add the real answer in case anybody comes looking here)